# First element clicked show first modal, second element clicked show second modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like in the thread. I want to show first modal by clicking on the first 'td'. Next I want to show second modal by clicking on the second 'td' and so on. How can I do thbis with a classes not in ids? Here's the example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="modal">modal1</div>
  <div class="modal">modal2</div>
  <div class="modal">modal3</div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/znzjeaq4/

Comment: This is what IDs are made for. Why can't you use them?

Comment: Have you tried [nth child selectors](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)?

Comment: @Stephen S
I know that I can use IDs but I don't know how many elements I will use to this so that I need to use classes. Yes, I tried it, same, a lot of code.

Comment: @Hvrxld are you adding them dynamically? IE, can you add an ID that is like `td` + a counter?

Comment: Number of TDs depends on rows in the database.

Comment: @Hvrxld right, but can you name the ID of them dynamically? Are you able to say that the ID name is `id1` for the first row, `id2` for the second row, etc.

Comment: Yes, I can do this. Have you got solution for that?

Comment: @Hvrxld yup, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/znzjeaq4/2/)

You want to assign IDs to your TDs and modals:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td id="1">td</td>
      <td id="2">td</td>
      <td id="3">td</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id="4">td</td>
      <td id="5">td</td>
      <td id="6">td</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="modal" id="m1">modal1</div>
  <div class="modal" id="m2">modal2</div>
  <div class="modal" id="m3">modal3</div>
  <div class="modal" id="m4">modal4</div>
  <div class="modal" id="m5">modal5</div>
  <div class="modal" id="m6">modal6</div>
```

And then, on TD click, get the ID and then use that ID for the modal:

```
$("td").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#m" + id).show();
})
```

Comment: Cheers. Thats what I want. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

So, the first example is using nth-child to pick and choose among the multiple class elements, then :active/:focus to initiate an action upon the click.

```css
.modal {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal:nth-child(1):active,
.modal:nth-child(1):focus {
  background: green;
}
.modal:nth-child(2):active,
.modal:nth-child(2):focus {
  background: blue;
}
.modal:nth-child(3):active,
.modal:nth-child(3):focus {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal"></div>
<div class="modal"></div>
<div class="modal"></div>
```

**JS**

With JavaScript you can choose each class, if it doesn't have an ID, by doing something similar to CSS's nth-child, which is `('modal')[0]`.  So, `document.getElementsByClassName` grabs all the .modal divs and `('modal')[0]`, `('modal')[1]`, `('modal')[3]` would be how you select each on (starting with "0" as the first of the elements you're counting through.)  The JS example can get more detailed, but this is simply focusing on "Click this, do that..." (as if you were clicking to launch a related modal.)

```js
var modal_001 = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0];
var modal_002 = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[1];
var modal_003 = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[2];

modal_001.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.style.background = "green";
});

modal_002.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.style.background = "blue";
});

modal_003.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.style.background = "red";
});
```

```css
.modal {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal"></div>
<div class="modal"></div>
<div class="modal"></div>
```